# How to convert sympy expression which include integral and derivative to numpy

Tags: numpy, sympy

It may be normal to convert sympy expression to numpy, But my equation has Integral, Derivation on the output of the sympy. I tried lambdify but it gives me "name 'Integral' is not defined" Now, I get stuck, any help will be appreciated.

```
    

def plpwfun(w,b):
    plpw=-pi**2*(-w*exp(b + w)/(exp(b + w) + 1)**2 + (2*b + w)*exp(b + w)/(exp(b + w) + 1) - log(exp(b) + 1) + log(exp(b + w) + 1) + 1/(exp(b + w) + 1) - 1/(exp(b) + 1)) + 0.5*Integral(2*((-re(w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2) + re(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)))*(-Derivative(re(w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2), w) + Derivative(re(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)), w)) + (-im(w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2) + im(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)))*(-Derivative(im(w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2), w) + Derivative(im(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)), w)))*Abs(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1) - w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2)*sign(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1) - w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2)/(w**2*exp(b + w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1) - w**2*exp(2*b + 2*w*x)/(exp(b + w*x) + 1)**2), (x, 0, 1))
    return plpw

print(plpwfun(0,0))
```

I use the sympy output to be my gradient function(plpw,pwpb), but I can't convert them to numpy and calculate. Is there any ways I could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the newly released sympy 1.7?

```
pip install sympy --upgrade
```

Confirm by running

```
import sympy
print(sympy.__version__)
```

It includes a change to support Integral with lambdify: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/20134

You'll probably want to have scipy installed as well (so the function generated by `lambdify` will use scipy's `quad` or `nquad` otherwise mpmath will be required to run the generated function as a fallback).

For example this will work in 1.7

```
from sympy import *
x,y = symbols("x y")
i = Integral(x, (x, 0, y))
f = lambdify([y], i)
print(f(3))  # 4.5
```

If this doesn't work, could you can edit your question to show self contained code with the actual sympy `Integral` you're trying to `lambdify`?

Comment: You'll still have problems if the sympy expression you're trying to `lambdify` contains unevauated `Derivative` instances however.